# Ranking aggregated values in panel data

Tags: panel, stata, ranking

I have an unbalanced panel data set with daily data similar to this, for n countries:

```
quarter date id trade trade_quarterly rank       i
 1       1    1    1    2               1        10
 1       2    1    1    2               1        17
 1       1    2    1    1               2        12

 2       1    1    0    1               1        5
 2       2    1    1    1               1        9
 2       1    2    0    1               1        14
 2       2    2    1    1               1        8
 2       2    3    0    0               3        6
```

Given are the first 4 columns.

Interested in information i, I would now like to keep only the **2 most traded ids** for each quarter. I aggregated quarterly trades with

```
bysort quarter id: egen trade_quarterly =sum(trade)
```

to get column 5.

To calculate column 6, I tried using

```
bysort quarter id : egen xx =rank(trade_quarterly), "option"
```

which does not appear to produce the correct solution.

(Note that since the values are *aggregated within ids* ranking with `rank(xx), field` would produce a wrong rank for the following id)

Comment: Column 6 tells us that in the first quarter, id 1 is ranked first and id 2 is ranked second. And in the second quarter, id 1 and id 2 are tied for first, and id 3 is third (because id 1 and id 2 are both ranked above it).

Comment: Yes, indeed. What is critical here, is that _trade_quarterly_ does not vary within an id, but that it is possible that ids are tied in that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of syntax

```
bysort quarter id : egen xx =rank(trade_quarterly), option
```

is not legal, as the literal text `option` is itself not an option. More generally, `egen, rank()` can not help here with your present data structure.

But consider this, just a matter of a `collapse` to sums (totals) and then keeping only the largest two (the last two after sorting) within cross-combinations:

```
clear 
input quarter date id trade 
 1       1    1    1    2   
 1       2    1    1    2   
 1       1    2    1    1   
 2       1    1    0    1   
 2       2    1    1    1   
 2       1    2    0    1   
 2       2    2    1    1   
 2       2    3    0    0   
end 
collapse (sum) trade, by(quarter id) 
bysort quarter (trade) : keep if (_N - _n) < 2 
list, sepby(id quarter) 

     +----------------------+
     | quarter   id   trade |
     |----------------------|
  1. |       1    2       1 |
     |----------------------|
  2. |       1    1       2 |
     |----------------------|
  3. |       2    1       1 |
     |----------------------|
  4. |       2    2       1 |
     +----------------------+
```

If you don't want to `collapse`, then extra technique is to tag each `id`-`quarter` pair just once when ranking.

```
clear 
input quarter date id trade 
 1       1    1    1    2   
 1       2    1    1    2   
 1       1    2    1    1   
 2       1    1    0    1   
 2       2    1    1    1   
 2       1    2    0    1   
 2       2    2    1    1   
 2       2    3    0    0   
end 
egen sum = total(trade), by(quarter id) 
egen tag = tag(quarter id) 
bysort tag quarter (trade) : gen tokeep = tag & (_N - _n) < 2 
bysort quarter id (tokeep) : replace tokeep = tokeep[_N] 
list if tokeep, sepby(quarter) 

     +--------------------------------------------------+
     | quarter   date   id   trade   sum   tag   tokeep |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  1. |       1      2    1       1     2     0        1 |
  2. |       1      1    1       1     2     1        1 |
  3. |       1      1    2       1     1     1        1 |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  4. |       2      2    1       1     1     0        1 |
  5. |       2      1    1       0     1     1        1 |
  6. |       2      2    2       1     1     0        1 |
  7. |       2      1    2       0     1     1        1 |
     +--------------------------------------------------+
```

Note, in agreement with @William Lisowski's comment, that the largest two may not be uniquely identifiable in the presence of ties.

Comment: Many thanks Nick. However, I am originally interested in id data on daily level, which I had not sufficiently shown in the data breakdown above. I have edited my question accordingly.Is there a way around it?

Comment: I don't understand what is different in principle. Clearly you can `collapse` other variables alongside `trade`.

Comment: Once I use `collapse` on any variable, I will aggregate i, which is not the aim. The daily structure of the data should be kept. The only goal of the procedure is to filter out the x most traded ids.